# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError while using mongo-connector

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am following [this](https://community.toadworld.com/platforms/nosql/b/weblog/archive/2017/02/03/indexing-mongodb-data-in-apache-solr) to connect `solr` with `mongo`. when I invoke `mongo-connector` I get the following error.

```
$ mongo-connector --unique-key=id -n test.films -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr/#/films -d solr_doc_manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mongo-connector", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 104, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 1275, in main
    conf.parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/config.py", line 120, in parse_args
    option, dict((k, values.get(k)) for k in option.cli_names))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 1024, in apply_doc_managers
    dm_instances.append(DocManager(target_url, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py", line 80, in __init__
    self._build_fields()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 35, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py", line 97, in _build_fields
    result = decoder.decode(declared_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The database I am using is created from the examples film data provided with solr. Here is the `schema.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="directed_by" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
<field name="initial_release_date" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false"/>
<field name="genre" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false"/>
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
<fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
<fieldType name="long" class="solr.LongPointField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
</schema>
```

I have searched online and checked issues on `github` but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The path you've given to the Solr collection is not a valid endpoint for Solr. The URL goes to the local admin interface (and has a local anchor, which will never be seen by the server). That URL is meant for human consumption, and will serve HTML (and not JSON which the connector expects).

If you use the actual collection endpoint instead:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/films
```

.. that error message should disappear. If you reference the guide you're following, you can se that they're using the same format: `-t http://localhost:8983/solr/wlslog` (without the local, meant-for-a-browser anchor).